# Principal Ideal Domain Modulo a Power of a Prime Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

If $R$ is a PID, $p$ is a prime element of $R$, $R/(p)$ is finite, and $\alpha$ is a positive integer, is it true that $\vert R/(p^{\alpha})\vert=\vert R/(p)\vert^{\alpha}$? I seem to recall seeing this somewhere, and it seems to be true intuitively, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you asking only about an equality of size (cardinality)?

Comment: Yes. Just cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This follows from the exact sequence
$$0 \to R/p \xrightarrow{p^n} R/p^{n+1} \to R/p^n \to 0.$$

Comment: The notation $R/p \xrightarrow{p^n} R/p^{n+1}$ is misleading - this is not multiplication by $p^n$ (which is $0$ on $R/p$). The kernel of the natural map $R/p^{n+1} \twoheadrightarrow R/p^n$ is $p^n/p^{n+1}$, which is isomorphic to $R/p$ here because $p$ is a nonzerodivisor

Comment: Of course I mean the homomorphism induced by $p^n : R \to R$ (which is multiplication by $p^n$). Why should this be misleading? For example, I have seen the notation $\mathbb{Z}/2 \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z}/4$ several times.

Comment: You are right that $p^n : R/p \to R/p$ is trivial, but $p^n : R/p \to R/p^{n+1}$ is not.

Comment: A short exact sequence of $R$-modules?

Comment: The reason I find this notation misleading is because of the implicit identification of $R/p$ with the submodule $p^n/p^{n+1}$ of $R/p^{n+1}$. There *is* an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/2 \cong 2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, which is thought of as multiplication by $2$, but that only happens on the level $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z}/4$, i.e. *before* quotienting by the kernel, and not after.

Comment: @hardmath: Yes, this is a short exact sequence of $R$-modules

Comment: There is no implicit identification here. The exact sequence holds as stated.